# MongoDB vs Redis for user sessions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, redis

I need to load a few fields of information that changes infrequently for validation of routes that a user might access.

Currently, I query mongodb and store those fields in redis alongside any particular state information in a single hash that is keyed by `'user:' + mongodb_user_objectid` when a user logs in.

Then I create a session for the http cookie and store this key as a string in redis as well keyed by `'sess:' + session_id`.

Would it be better to not copy over the fields from mongodb and deal with updating both redis and mongodb when one of those validation fields may change?

Is there a significant performance difference from reading and writing this session information directly from/to mongodb without using redis as a middleman?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, a definite answer will require a **measurement using your setup** because there are so many potential factors.

However, *my guess* is that the overhead of using two datastores outweighs any potential advantages because the reads should be incredibly fast on both DBs:

- Since the sessions will be used often, the collection keeps pretty 'hot' so it will probably remain in RAM if any possible in MongoDB, too
- Losing a session wouldn't be great, but it's not a disaster, so you can write to MongoDB without waiting for a journal commit (which is pretty much the same reliability redis has)
- In either case, most time is (probably) spent on the network stack, and you have to go through that for both DBs

So, in a nutshell, I don't see any reasons why redis would be a lot faster in this case, but again, performance is often guesswork, especially when the details are unknown.

Comment: I totally agree re. measuring. Re. the guessing part - while I'm less intimate with MongoDB, two of Redis' classic use cases are session management and DB acceleration/caching. Specifically, since MongoDB isn't an in-memory database, it is commonly augmented with Redis where performance matters (e.g. http://redislabs.com/blog/the-top-3-game-changing-redis-use-cases :))

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's all very true, but as the link points out, redis really shines when it comes to also *modifying* the session *often*, keeping hit counts, request counts, etc. up to date. That's a point where it makes sense to separate faster and bulkier operations, and to ensure the repeated writes go to RAM only. However, the OP didn't say he was  writing very often, and even then, it has to be a lot of traffic to become an important difference.

Comment: So, since mongodb loads entire documents into memory, would it be a waste of RAM if I only need to use a few fields from the user's mongodb document in a session?

Comment: Well, maybe. However, that sounds like premature optimization to me(unless your user documents are huge or you already have millions of users, e.g.: 200 bytes x 1M users = 200M which is only 2.5% of 8G...), second I'd suggest to separate stuff like a `session` (which is ephemeral) from very important, persistent data like `user` where possible.